# how to use transform: rotate as hover?

Tags: html, css, transform

I am trying to rotate 3 divs (cubes)  on a hover state but it seems that not every browser can handle this. Only IE Edge without problem. 
Firefox works great with the first 2 divs on hover but the cube disappears when hovering on the 3rd.
Chrome starts shaking all the cubes when hovering.

Is there something wrong in my code?

```css
.cube-a,
.cube-b,
.cube-c {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(108deg) rotateY(16deg) rotateZ(192deg);
}

.cube-a .tcface,
.cube-b .tcface,
.cube-c .tcface {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.cube-a .cube-a-face {
  background-color: #f4e00d;
  /* geel */
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotatez(180deg) translateY(-50px) translateZ(50px);
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-b .cube-b-face {
  background-color: #8db63c;
  /* groen */
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotatez(180deg) translateY(-50px) translateZ(50px);
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-c .cube-c-face {
  background-color: #009de0;
  /* blauw */
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotatez(180deg) translateY(-50px) translateZ(50px);
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-a .cube-a-right,
.cube-c .cube-c-right {
  background-color: #8db63c;
  /* groen */
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-b .cube-b-right {
  background-color: #f4e00d;
  /* geel */
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-a .cube-a-bottom,
.cube-b .cube-b-bottom {
  background-color: #009de0;
  /* blauw */
}

.cube-c .cube-c-bottom {
  background-color: #f4e00d;
  /* geel */
}

.cube-a-bottom,
.cube-b-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.cube-a-face,
.cube-a-right,
.cube-a-bottom,
.cube-b-face,
.cube-b-right,
.cube-b-bottom,
.cube-c-face,
.cube-c-right,
.cube-c-bottom {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 92px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Simply Rounded Bold";
}

.cube-a:hover,
.cube-b:hover,
.cube-c:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cube-a">
  <div class="tcface cube-a-face">A</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-a-right">B</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-a-bottom">C</div>
</div>

<div class="cube-b">
  <div class="tcface cube-b-face">B</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-b-right">A</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-b-bottom">C</div>
</div>

<div class="cube-c">
  <div class="tcface cube-c-face">C</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-c-right">B</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-c-bottom">A</div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8vuj7peb/100/

Comment: When the cube is rotated, the mouse isn't on it, so it's not `:hover` anymore.

Comment: Try adding  `-webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 2s;` to make it much smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-webkit-transition: all 1s;` and `transition: all 1s;`. This is the [transition property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp), making the transition `1s` long.

```css
.cube-a,
.cube-b,
.cube-c {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(108deg) rotateY(16deg) rotateZ(192deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
}

.cube-a .tcface,
.cube-b .tcface,
.cube-c .tcface {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.cube-a .cube-a-face {
  background-color: #f4e00d;
  /* geel */
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotatez(180deg) translateY(-50px) translateZ(50px);
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-b .cube-b-face {
  background-color: #8db63c;
  /* groen */
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotatez(180deg) translateY(-50px) translateZ(50px);
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-c .cube-c-face {
  background-color: #009de0;
  /* blauw */
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotatez(180deg) translateY(-50px) translateZ(50px);
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-a .cube-a-right,
.cube-c .cube-c-right {
  background-color: #8db63c;
  /* groen */
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-b .cube-b-right {
  background-color: #f4e00d;
  /* geel */
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.cube-a .cube-a-bottom,
.cube-b .cube-b-bottom {
  background-color: #009de0;
  /* blauw */
}

.cube-c .cube-c-bottom {
  background-color: #f4e00d;
  /* geel */
}

.cube-a-bottom,
.cube-b-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.cube-a-face,
.cube-a-right,
.cube-a-bottom,
.cube-b-face,
.cube-b-right,
.cube-b-bottom,
.cube-c-face,
.cube-c-right,
.cube-c-bottom {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 92px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Simply Rounded Bold";
}

.cube-a:hover,
.cube-b:hover,
.cube-c:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cube-a">
  <div class="tcface cube-a-face">A</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-a-right">B</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-a-bottom">C</div>
</div>

<div class="cube-b">
  <div class="tcface cube-b-face">B</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-b-right">A</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-b-bottom">C</div>
</div>

<div class="cube-c">
  <div class="tcface cube-c-face">C</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-c-right">B</div>
  <div class="tcface cube-c-bottom">A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe a little bit faster... ;-)

Comment: Awesome solution! And even better because of the delay. thanks for the solution